# Update Song time label

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, mpmediaitem

The app is a music player, and I need to show a `trackTimeLabel` that updates the playback duration during the song.

**So, update the label every second with the playback track time duration.**

Right now I'm doing a hack where I am just counting seconds that have nothing to do with the song, but that's not a good solution:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
    _titleLabel.text = [self currentItemValue:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerDidTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void) timerDidTick:(NSTimer*) theTimer{
    long currentPlaybackTime = musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
    int currentHours = (int)(currentPlaybackTime / 3600);                         
    int currentMinutes = (int)((currentPlaybackTime / 60) - currentHours*60);     // Whole minutes
    int currentSeconds = (currentPlaybackTime % 60);                        
    _trackTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02d:%02d", currentHours, currentMinutes, currentSeconds];
}
```

Apple has a `MPMediaItem` class which I can get a `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration` for the track, but I can't seem to get anything working with that.

Comment: Are you trying to get an actual real-time reading of how much time is either remaining or elapsed during a track play?

Comment: @CraigSmith yup exactly, sorry if I didn't explain that well enough, but you got it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

In your ViewController.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    AVAudioPlayer * player;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *seekSlider;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
```

**Step 2**

In your ViewController.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURL * fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"01 - Saturday Saturday - DownloadMing.SE" withExtension:@"mp3"];

    NSError * error = nil;

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];



    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Error : %@ ", error);

    [player prepareToPlay];

    player.volume = 0.5;

    self.seekSlider.maximumValue = player.duration;
}
-(void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{


    float progress = player.currentTime;
    //    if(!self.seekSlider.isFocused)
    self.seekSlider.value = progress;

    _lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f:%.2d", (progress / 60), ((int)progress % 60 )];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)play_pause_clicked:(id)sender {


    if(player.playing)
    {
        [player pause];
        [(UIButton*)sender setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [player play];
        [(UIButton*)sender setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    }


}


- (IBAction)seekPlayer:(id)sender {

    player.currentTime = [(UISlider*)sender value];


}
- (IBAction)changeVolume:(id)sender {

    player.volume = [(UISlider*)sender value];


}
```

This is perfect working code for me... Try this, I hope, this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting 0:00 as the time no matter what on that though.  Also, am I just calling that with `NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` or am I doing something different with it?

Comment: are you not solve your issue??...if not,whats the error now??

Comment: I'm getting 0:00 as the time no regardless of what point the song is at.  And where should I be calling these methods from?

Comment: See My Updated answer bro.. this will definitely help you

Comment: That didn't work, I had most of that stuff.  Thanks for the help though-